# Search and replace with a substring that was matched?

Tags: r, regex

Apologies this is a dup because I cannot seem to find a solution. Suppose I have a vector as such.

```
162_562-5_ZE5_ONE
163_662-5_AE5_ZERO
```

However I would like to remove all patterns except for ZE5 and AE5 and append AC. in front.  Is there a way to grep this and retain part of the string so that I can append something to it.  Ideally the new vector would return AC.ZE5, AC.AE5 only.  I can do two `gsub` supposedly but I'm wondering if I can specifically retain a certain part of the search and append something to it.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` in base R, extract `"ZE5"` or `"AE5"` and add `"AC."` in the beginning of each.

```
sub(".*(ZE5|AE5).*", "AC.\\1", x)
#[1] "AC.ZE5" "AC.AE5"
```

As mentioned by @Ahdee a more generic solution would be

```
sub("^\\d.*-\\d_(.*?)_.*", "AC.\\1", x)
```

**data**

```
x <- c("162_562-5_ZE5_ONE", "163_662-5_AE5_ZERO")
```

Comment: that is cool. I did not know about this function.  Any case in case someone else needs it here is a more generic in case the middle portion is unknown. `sub("^\\d.*-\\d_(.*?)_.*", "AC.\\1", test)`

Comment: @Ahdee are you looking for something else in the answer?

Comment: no its good. Can you do me a favor and edit with my code above so that it can be more generic?  that way it can match anything in between those pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to learn this. I wonder if you could also use `stringr`:

```
x <- c("162_562-5_ZE5_ONE", "163_662-5_AE5_ZERO")
paste0("AC.", stringr::str_extract(x, "ZE5|AE5"))
```